# How can I deal with Twitters facebook integration stretching og:image photos?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Facebook expects `og:image` to be 200x200 for normal sharing:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/static/image/200x200.jpeg">
```

However if someone uses Twitter auto Facebook sharing functionality, the image gets used with an aspect ratio of 1.91:1, which causes my square og:image to be stretched.

Is it possible to cater to both of these use cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Facebook inconsistently displays sharing images and it extends beyond graph posts.

- If you use a widescreen sharing image for the nicer timeline sharing
  posts it'll get cropped in the middle when using sharer.php which displays a square non-centered preview. So you're basically forced to use the square ones.
- For sharing on twitter simply don't include og:image on the sharing URL.